Can $\exists$ be transformed into enumeration in the case of a finite domain?
For example,  according to the union axiom,$$a\in \bigcup\{u,v\}\Leftrightarrow \exists w\in \{u,v\}\,(a\in w)$$
Since
$\{u,v\}$ contains only two elements, can this proposition be directly replaced by enumeration as follows?
$$
a\in \bigcup\{u,v\}\Leftrightarrow (a\in u\lor a\in v)
$$
If so, how does this replacement use the proposition $w\in\{u,v\}\Leftrightarrow (w=u\lor w=v)$？ I am unsure how to incorporate this proposition into the original statement to derive the final result. Is there a more rigorous theory regarding $\exists$ that addresses this?

Yes, of course. $\exists$ "works" like disjunction. Thus, for finite domains you can simply write $x=a \lor x=b \lor \ldots \lor x=z$. The same for $\forall$ that works as a conjunction.

@RobArthan it's not wrong. If $u = v = \mathbb{N}$ then $a \in \mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow \exists w \in {\mathbb{N}}. a \in w$, as expected.

@NaïmFavier: apologies. I misread the question.

Keep in mind that all quantifications are unbounded in single-sorted first-order logic (which ZF is based upon): formally, $$\exists w\in\{u, v\}. a \in w$$ is shorthand for $$\exists w. w \in \{u, v\} \land a \in w$$
Now by definition of $\{u, v\}$ (the axiom of pairing) this is equivalent to $$\exists w. (w = u \lor w = v) \land a \in w$$
We can distribute $\land$ over $\lor$ to get $$\exists w. (w = u \land a \in w) \lor (w = v \land a \in w)$$ and distribute $\exists$ over $\lor$ to get $$(\exists w. w = u \land a \in w) \lor (\exists w. w = v \land a \in w)$$
Finally, you should convince yourself that $\exists x. x = y \land P(x)$ is equivalent to $P(y)$¹, so that this is equivalent to $$a \in u \lor a \in v$$

¹ And dually $\forall x. x = y \to P(x)$ is equivalent to $P(y)$. This is a simple form of the Yoneda lemma.

Your answer was really helpful, thank you! So, can I consider $[\exists x. x=y\land P(x)]\Leftrightarrow P(y)$ as a logical axiom?

Well, it's not an axiom, it's a theorem. You can prove it from the equality axioms.

Thank you! Is my understanding correct that using the axiom of substitution, we can prove $(\Rightarrow)$, and for $(\Leftarrow)$, there indeed  exists $y=y$ such that $P(y)$ holds true? It seems I can't elaborate further on this. I feel that $\exists$ and $\forall$ are quite subtle, and differ from logical connectives defined by truth tables.

@user1361001 yes, that's all there is to it.
